# TestNG and Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, testng, beancreationexception

What is the best practice way to do unit testing with Spring? I assume the combination TestNG & jmockit with Spring 3 isn't bad, so that's what I'm doing right now, but if I'm off course selecting the tools for my fresh Spring project, please tell me right away. :-)

Anyways, I've created an entity that I want to test, but I'm not sure how to actually run the TestNG from the Spring context. I've created a simple test class

```
package com.mydomain.data.entities.test;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.*;

@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:applicationContext.xml"}) 
public class SimpleTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @BeforeClass
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertNotNull(applicationContext);
    }

    @Test
    public void testNothing() {

    }

}
```

with applicationContext.xml importing beans for setting up the model and business layer. First off all, I'd like it to use the applicationContext.xml from Project/WebRoot/WEB-INF, whereas the source for this test lives in Project/src/com/mydomain/data/entities/test, but I believe that /applicationContext.xml would give me Projects/src, same as classpath:  Is this correct?

Furthermore, now that I'm using the model and business layers that my web application would use, I should expect it to behave similarly. But, when I launch TestNG on the test, it sais:
class org.hibernate.cfg.ExtendedMappings has interface org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings as super class:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in URL [file:/Users/niklas/Documents/Eclipse/Project/WebRoot/WEB-INF/Project-Model.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.hibernate.cfg.ExtendedMappings has interface org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings as super class
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:449)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:286)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:352)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:266)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:77)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
    at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeAwareMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1414)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1381)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.hibernate.cfg.ExtendedMappings has interface org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings as super class
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:700)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:319)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:330)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:254)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.createExtendedMappings(AnnotationConfiguration.java:187)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:277)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:667)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1390)
    ... 53 more
```

What is this and why am I getting this? Any clues?

My sessionFactory looks like this

```
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="annotatedClasses">
      <list>
       <!-- Entity classes from package com.mydomain.data.entities -->
      </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
      <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
      </props>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

Comment: SPring's testing support is for integration testing, not unit testing.  You can use plain JUnit or TestNG for unit testing.  So what testing are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now the problem doesn't seem to be related to any of Spring or TestNG. The key part is:

```
 java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.hibernate.cfg.ExtendedMappings has interface org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings as super class
```

Are you sure your CLASSPATH is OK? I.e. you have compatible version of Hibernate modules and no repetitions there?

What if you create a simple TestNG test that does the following:

```
Class.forName("org.hibernate.cfg.ExtendedMappings");
```

?

Comment: So if I give the test an empty context I can run a test that includes Class.forName, that gives me: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.hibernate.cfg.ExtendedMappings has interface org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings as super class  But when I run the same in my servlet context, I don't have a problem. And they have the same classpath.

Comment: I believe the only place ExtendedMappings is defined in any of my jar-files is in hibernate-annotations.jar.

Comment: Hmm, this may be because I'm running Hibernate 3.5-beta1 with Hibernate-Annotations 3.4. Let me try and downgrade to 3.4 and see if they're more aligned then :-)

Comment: When looking at:
http://fisheye.jboss.org/browse/Hibernate/core/trunk/core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/cfg/Mappings.java
you can see that org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings is an interface in one of the versions (15365) and a class in other (11588). That confirms the suspicion of wrong Hibernate JARs being used.

Comment: Err... 3.4 doesn't exist. So I'll give Hibernate Core 3.3.2 with Hibernate Annotations 3.4 a try

Comment: You may find useful the Compability Matrix of Hibernate modules: https://www.hibernate.org/6.html#A3 .

Comment: Thanks a bunch. You are, of course, very correct in your suspicion. Going back to 3.3.2 aligned core and annotations again. :-)

Answer (score 7):

Your test ckass needs to extend [AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/testng/AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.html). Or if your code is testing database acces another useful class to extend is [AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/test/context/testng/AbstractTransactionalTestNGSpringContextTests.html).

Comment: Thanks you very much. Extending AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests made it load the context, but it gives me a strange exception while initializing. I've updated my question with the exceptions it gives to my context

Comment: Please vote this up as it is the answer to the original question and is what I was looking for (eg: Using Spring with TestNG )

Answer (score 1):

Consult the chapter on TestNG in the Spring documentation:

- for [Spring 2.5](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/testing.html#testcontext-support-classes-testng).
- for [Spring 3.0](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ch09s03.html#testcontext-support-classes-testng)

Comment: Don't worry, I only wrote here after reading "Spring TestContext Framework" in the Spring 3 Reference manual twice and reading quite a few tutorials

Answer (score 1):

For me this problem was caused because I had different hibernate versions included myself, not because of a third party including them. A sweep of your project/poms to make sure you youserlf are only using one hibernate version is worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try hibernate-annotations-3.5.0-Beta-1 as this aligns with hibernate-core-3.5.0-Beta-1.

I still get the java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError sometimes, as I'm trying to use hibernate search which is using the "old" annotations.

Also, not sure if you are running JBoss, but if you are you'll get this error with core 3.5.0.

Comment: If you're using hibernate-core-3.5.x, it should include the annotations (and entityManager) - separate jars no longer required according to hibernate https://www.hibernate.org/397.html

Comment: That's what i thought, but I still need to pull annotations in.  If you look at hibernate-annotations pom it has hibernate-core as a dependency.  What i think hibernate means is that the version numbers are aligned.  Or have I been drinking too much beer :)