# java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError

Tags: hibernate

I'm trying to a JPA annotation one -to- one. but getting following error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: class org.hibernate.cfg.ExtendedMappings has interface org.hibernate.cfg.Mappings as super class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.createExtendedMappings(AnnotationConfiguration.java:182)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:272)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1377)
at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:859)
at com.HiberAnnJS.main(HiberAnnJS.java:21)
```

I don't know what i have to do.

Comment: The same problem is seen in the next [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497619/testng-and-spring-3)

Answer (score 13):

I think you are using **incompatible versions of hibernate core and annotations**. One of the possible combination is **Hibernate Core 3.3.2 with Hibernate Annotations 3.4** and try. Have a look at the **Compatibility matrix** [here](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HibernateCompatibilityMatrix) for more details.